# C# Object Array Changing all element properties

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Just started learning C# and struggling to understand what is happening. Here is a simplified version of my problem.

I have two classes called Dog and Kennel. Kennel houses a 2D array of type Dog. Dog has multiple properties (breed, color), but just _name is all we need for this example.

I want to change the name of a single dog. I tried:

```
kennel.Dogs[4,4].Name = "Fido"
```

but it sets ALL the dogs to the name of "Fido". Not just the dog at (4, 4). Why?

Example:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        Kennel kennel = new Kennel();
        
        kennel.Dogs[4,4].Name = "Fido";
        Console.WriteLine(kennel.Dogs[4,4].Name); //Expectation: Fido; Result: Fido
        Console.WriteLine(kennel.Dogs[2,2].Name); //Expectation: Bowser; Result: Fido
    }
}

class Kennel {
    public Kennel() {
        this._dogs = new Dog[10,10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
           for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
               _dogs[i, j] = defaultDog;
               defaultDog.Name = "Bowser";
           }
        }
    }
    private string _name;
    private Dog defaultDog = new Dog();
    private Dog[,] _dogs;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public Dog[,] Dogs
    {
        get { return _dogs; }
        set { _dogs = value; }
    }
}
class Dog {
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of including the entire code you should try to extract a [mcve] that everyone is able to compile and try themselves. Sometimes you are even able to determine the cause of your bug while you are creating said example

Comment: This is a unity game, and the actual code would be really difficult to reproduce. I think it would only work to confuse those who might be able to help. 

Besides, if I am correct... this is not a bug but the intended functionality of the C# language. I just think I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Can we please see the definition of the Dog.Name property, and any fields that it touches?

Comment: Also, can we see the code where you populate the array? Is it possible you have created a single object and put a reference to the same object in multiple cells in the array?

Comment: Also, what is `Dogs` and how is it related to `_dogs`?

Comment: @ragnvaldr.js You don't need to provide the entire code for you application, you need to provide the *smallest* snippet *that still reproduces the problem*.  So pull out only the code where you're manipulating this array, ensure that that snippet on its own, when run, causes the problem, and then provide *that*.

Comment: @ragnvaldr.js If the full code is too difficult to reproduce *you* have to boil down the real problem to its core. Only then can you figure out why it is happening

Comment: _"This constructed scenario though should simulate the issue I am having."_ - except it doesn't. There is nothing in the code you show that should reproduce the behavior you claim. The relevant code is at least the `Dog` and `Kennel` classes. Copy-paste the relevant code to a new Console Application in Visual Studio (or dotnetfiddle, or ...) and make sure it shows the behavior you show.

Comment: "nothing in the code you show that should reproduce the behavior you claim" That was all the information I was looking for.... This was not meant to debugging-ish question. I just wanted to know if this was expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks everyone for jumping on this question... I will create another more detailed question if I need further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three scenarios I can that would lead to this symptom:

1. You only actually have one `Dog` object, and each cell in the array is a reference to that single object; if so: fix your array initialization to create multiple different objects; it doesn't *appear* that this is the case, based on the code in the question
2. You have multiple `Dog` objects, but the field that holds the name is a `static` field; if so: fix the field (remove the `static`)
3. You have multiple `Dog` objects, but the name is via a separate reference to another intermediate object that is shared between them all; if so: fix the intermediate references